Why can't I see set menu for switching between orientation and rotation in AE?
In the tutorial video, I saw that there's a Set menu for switching between Orientation and Rotation in AE. Here's a screen.

But I don't have it. There is just rotation and no way to turn on Orientation.

How to turn on this Set menu?

please add link to tutorial for reference, and the version of AE you're using

@tomh I added the link

are you using an old version of ae?

@tomh nope, 2023

I think you have selected the Selection Tool.
Make a text layer.
Make the layer 3d.
If you select the Rotation Tool, the options shown appear.
If you select the Selection Tool, they disappear.
If you try to use the weird new rotation tool (no idea what it does) that appears to the right, they also do not appear.


Yeah, I see this now. It's like there are 2 rotation tools. Thanks!
